# удалить лишний атрибут из класса html

Tags: python, html, парсер, lxml

сделал парсер, который выводит текст стиха с сайта: https://stihibase.ru/author/t/tjutchev/vesennjaja_groza/
но, помимо текста, выводит еще block-poema-left-control и пишет: "по теме и по автору". а мне это нужно удалить [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://stihibase.ru/author/t/tjutchev/vesennjaja_groza/'
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
temp = bs.find('article', 'block-poema')
print(temp.text)
```

Comment: приложите код парсера

Comment: хорошо, приложил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://stihibase.ru/author/t/tjutchev/vesennjaja_groza/'
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
# выбираем только параграфы
temp = bs.find('article', 'block-poema').find_all('p')
# соединяем их в текст    
print('\n'.join(x.text for x in temp))
```

Comment: спасибо большое! все получилось.